# how to update data of a struct and save it in chaincode?

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger

The following is an excerpt of the chaincode where I have created a customer struct that saves basic info. I wish to write an update function that first fetches the details of the customer with the UID(args[0]) and then appends/updates the Country as per the second arguement of the function update and finally saves the updated data.
What am I doing wrong?  Also I would like to know the concept of Marshal and Unmarshal.

```
type Customer struct {
  UID     string
  Name    string
  Address struct {
    StreetNo string
    Country  string
  }
}
func (t *SimpleChaincode) update(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) ([]byte, error) {


if len(args) != 2 {
    return nil, errors.New("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting name of the key to query")
}
  //args[0] to get the UID of customer whose details to be updated
  //args[1] data that needs to be updated 

data,err:= stub.GetState(ars[0])
if err != nil {
     return nil, err
}
json.Unmarshal(data, &uid)
//append
data.Country= append(data.Country,args[1])
fmt.Printf("Risk Fag set for UID %s",data)

raw, err := json.Marshal(data)
  if err != nil {
     return nil, err
  }

  stub.PutState(data.UID, raw)

return nil,nil

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example of marshaling and unmarshaling structs to/from JSON in the Fabric chaincode examples.  It demonstrates how to read JSON data from the chain, update certain fields of the struct, and then re-save the JSON data to the chain.  See the transferMarble function in the example at:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/examples/chaincode/go/marbles02/marbles_chaincode.go

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a variable where the JSON package can put the decoded data.For example this will hold a map of strings to arbitrary data types:

```
map[string]interface{}

byt := []byte(`{"num":6.13,"strs":["a","b"]}`)
if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(dat)
```

the result is  :

```
map[num:6.13 strs:[a b]]
```